# Laws/ethics on using images hosted by another website as teasers?

Tags: images, copyright

I was wondering about the appropriate way to use an image hosted by another website as a teaser image in my own website. For example, if I am aggregating articles from sources including the NYTimes, can I present a teaser or thumbnail from the NYTimes website as part of the link/teaser summary on my own site?

What steps would I need to go through such as getting permission or attributing the primary source?

Comment: This answer should cover it for you: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86631/can-you-be-sued-for-using-publicly-used-images-on-a-blog-without-copyright-permi/86637#86637